# How to ensure that all ajax response handler code runs properly in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have an ajax-based application that sometimes needs to get multiple values at the same time based on a jquery selector. This works in all browsers, but in Firefox there's one quirk: Some of the response handlers run in a strange context, causing some weirdness:

- The debugger won't stop at breakpoints in them
- If they hit an alert, it's styled slightly differently (most apparent part of this is the width)
- (most importantly for my purposes) Selenium can't see the alert

All of these symptoms lead me to believe that the response handler isn't running on the normal single-threaded javascript engine. It's almost as if it's getting farmed out to a thread pool or something, but I can't find any documentation indicating this. My question, then, is: Is this a bug in Firefox, or is there something I should be doing to ensure that all my response handlers run in the same context?

Here's a fiddle that demonstrates my issue. If you run it in Chrome with dev tools open, it will hit the breakpoint before displaying each alert. But in Firefox, one alert will always show immediately, and you'll only ever hit one breakpoint.

http://jsfiddle.net/dfaonyku/11/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('div').each(function() {
   $.ajax({
     url: '/echo/json/',
      data: {
       json: JSON.stringify({'id': this.id}),
      },
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(response, status, xhr) {
       //console.log(response);
        debugger;
        alert(response.id);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">

</div>

<div id="bar">

</div>
```

Comment: You're asking so many questions, it's hard to tell what your issue is. The first question is a quirkiness in the debugger function in Firefox. The second issue is browser styling for alert, which is out of your control. I think the third question is about Selenium, but you didn't tag the question as Selenium.

Comment: All three of those things are symptoms of the same underlying issue: This ajax response handler is getting run in some separate context that's not attached to the javascript debugger, or to the webdriver session. My question is how I can ensure that all the response handlers run in the same context.